# How to prevent Mikogo from auto-starting

Tags: windows-7, boot

I use [Mikogo](http://www.mikogo.com) for screen sharing. The problem is that it always loads when I boot (on Win7). On the Settings screen there's a checkbox that says "Start program at computer startup" - which is unchecked and always has been. Still, it auto-starts. I tried ticking the checkbox, rebooting, clearing it again, which didn't help.

Any ideas how I can stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably stop it from loading with [msconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSConfig) or [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) rather than the software's own option. msconfig is built in, autoruns isn't, but autoruns is a lot more powerful.

Just find the process (in autoruns its under the 'logon' tab most likely,and under startup on msconfig) and untick it, and it should not start up the next boot

Comment: Thank you Journeyman Geek I can confirm that I was having the same issue as Vitaly and could not find the start up entry in msconfig. Autoruns worked a treat and it was sitting there (along with lots of other undesirable hidden items) under the logon tab. Thank you